# Using patented product as a part of my product.

Tags: paletterack, deign

I am designing a "bunk-bed" and would like to use a palette rack as steal frame. Specifically - Husky Palette Rack. This product has a "Beams feature the patented Bowlock® safety clip. Bowlock® cannot be sprung or removed without first removing the beam and requires no special tools." 
Later I plan to patent the design or my product itself, will I run into a problem if I am to incorporate the palette rack into my product (I plan to purchase the palette racks as a raw material for my "bunk-bed).

Q: Can I use Husky Palette Rack as a part of my product or do I need to contact the company for permission or should I use entirely different company ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is beyond the scope of this site to discuss whether the makers of the pallet rack may have contractual limitations on use so that they do not get sued when a product fails and drops a child on the ground.

With respect to using a patented part in a bigger system.  Happens all the time.  For example, you may use a battery or power supply that has patents as part of a device.  Microprocessors have lots of patents and are used in other devices.

To seek a utility patent you would need a non-obvious element in your patent application.  It is rare that making a new but not surprising use of an existing component is sufficient for patenting.  In your case it sounds like the principal difference is that you are holding bedding/people rather than pallets.

If you want to seek a design patent on the ornamental appearance of your bed, you may want your patent attorney to "ghost" the lines for the pallet (make the lines using dashed lines) so that is not part of your design but that is a question you will need to discuss.

If this is likely to be a moneymaker for you, you should consult a professional as there are many nuances that are best addressed in a consultation rather than in web posts.

Comment: Thank you for prompt response, I will consider this info and most likely consult an attorney on the subject, once I am ready to patent